# Why use constructor at all?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, apply, call

I came across the thought that I honestly never had to use class nor constructor all this time and started to wonder if there are cases where I should use them? For example, below codes are basically same except one uses constructor and one doesn't.

**Using constructor:**

```
function Food(foodName, foodPrice) {
   Currencies.call(this, foodPrice);
   this.category = 'food';
   this.name = foodName;
}

function Currencies(usd) {
   this.usd = usd;
   this.won = +usd * 1000;
}

const pizza = new Food('pizza', 30); // { usd: 30, won: 30000, category: 'food', name: 'pizza' }
const burger = new Food('burger', 10); // { usd: 30, won: 30000, category: 'food', name: 'pizza' }
```

**Not using constructor**

```
function food(foodName, foodPrice) {
   return { name: foodName, category: 'food', ...(currencies(foodPrice)) }
}

function currencies(usd) {
   return { usd, won: usd * 1000 }
}

const pizza = food('pizza', 30); // { usd: 30, won: 30000, category: 'food', name: 'pizza' }
const burger = food('burger', 10); // { usd: 30, won: 30000, category: 'food', name: 'pizza' }
```

To me, not using constructor seems bit simpler so I would avoid using it AMAP. What do you prefer and why? And when exactly do you decide to use constructor instead of "regular" function?

Comment: For code you're writing and implementing yourself, everything useful you can do with a constructor you can also do without one. I follow the same approach, I've always felt that plain functions work just as well and never felt any desire to use classes or constructors.

Comment: Decorators and dependency injection may be the only major difference (outside of the ones already mentioned) of using classes over functions but as of now that's highly dependent on what (if any) framework you're using. Interested to hear what other's come up with!

Comment: wow, i didn't know you can create classes with `function` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

A constructor enables you to write methods to the object itself, which you can not do without a constructor. In addition to that, you can provide custom initialization that must be done before any other methods can be called on an instantiated object. You can also inherit from one class to another using `extends` operator. This saves you time from re-writing the same thing over and over again and provides better and easier control over your objects.

Refer to the following link for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

Comment: This is strange. What do you mean "write methods to the object itself"? You can do that in a function prototype, inside the main function, as well as in a constructor? Also you can 'extend' by assigning the prototype to a function. `class` is _syntactic sugar_ on top of essentially "functions with prototypes". None of the advantages you list are _really_ advantages more than _preferences_. I use classes all the time, but out of preference - you could write all that as pure Functions as well... Except some extension like `HTMLElement`, but even that can be done using `Reflect`...

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of object properties is to put fields into instances and methods into prototypes to save memory and to enable inheritance. Granted, your examples do not include any object methods, but I'm guessing your question is broader than your examples.

When you use an object initializer or `new Object` to create an instance, the new instance gets `Object.prototype` as its prototype. True, you could put methods into `Object.prototype` but that is discouraged because the instances of all objects would inherit the methods. When you use an object constructor like `Food`, a new instance gets `Food.prototype` as its prototype which is dedicated to `Food` instances. So (if `Food` had methods) you could safely assign the methods to `Food.prototype`.

See also https://medium.com/hagenhaus/diagrams-of-javascript-constructors-0e348b67dfee.

Comment: "*Your second example uses two functions both wrapping `Object` which is a (standard built-in object) constructor.*" - uh, no, there is no call to `new Object` anywhere

Comment: @MattHagen ... Also the first example does not use two constructor functions. It instantiates `Food` only. Thus the latter serves as constructor function. The way `Currencies` gets applied follows a pattern which could be named _"applicator based mixin"_. Despite looking like a constructor, due to first uppercase letter and `this` within the function body, it is not ... though it could be used like a constructor function. But here the function gets applied via `call` to the freshly created `Food` instance. It's delegation, one of the many code-reuse patterns JavaScript does offer.

Comment: Note ... Angus Croll many years ago wrote an already classic essay about the above commented technique ... [_"Flight Mixins Are Awesome!"_](https://webreflection.blogspot.com/2013/04/flight-mixins-are-awesome.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Bergi and Peter Seliger. I tried to reflect your corrections in my entry above.

Comment: @MattHagen ... Regarding your linked article where you reflect on constructors and  where you say ... _"... to my knowledge, the only way to test for `[[Construct]]` is with the new operator."_. One actually can implement functionality which does detect whether a function/method is [callable](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-introspection/blob/develop/src/feature/isCallable.js#L118) and/or [constructible](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-introspection/blob/develop/src/feature/isConstructable.js#L25) without any kind of direct invocation.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, thanks. Yes, I got some help from a TC39 delegate, and modified the article accordingly. The technique uses Proxy.